# how do you browse between windows

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I started with Visual basic 2010 and wants to learn this program. I am reading some tutorials but there is one thing i can't find.

I want different sections in a program. I have added a menu with some options. Now when i click in the memo on the "personnel" option i want to show the personnel form. I did this with

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub NieuwToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NieuwToolStripMenuItem.Click
    formPersoneel.Show()
End Sub
End Class
```

This will open the form only in a new window. How can i load this forms in the program itself?

Answer (score 1):

a form is a "window", to load somthing in the main form you have to create à UserControl

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a multiple document interface MDI.

[Here is a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973874.aspx) to some explanation of this.

You have to set the `IsMdiContainer` property of your form to `True`